# AWS DynamoDB - Load data with Boto3 using JSON file as input

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

I have multiple tables in **Amazon DynamoDB**, **JSON Data** is currently uploaded into the tables using the `batch-write-item` command that is available as part of **AWS CLI** - this works well.

However I would like to use just **Python + Boto3** but have **not** been able to execute the **Boto** `BatchWriteItem` request with an external data file as input. I envision if there is a Boto3 script it would look like this shown below, but I have not been able to find documentation/examples for it.

**Example (Pseudo Code)**

```
table = dynamodb.Table(‘my_table’)
table.BatchWriteItem(RequestItems=file://MyData.json)
```

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best place to look would be Boto3's readthedocs here: https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item

As long as your JSON was formatted correctly for the request as in the example you could use:

```
f = open('MyData.json')
request_items = json.loads(f.read())
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response = client.batch_write_item(RequestItems=request_items)
```

Answer (score 1):

I loaded the JSON this way

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodbclient=boto3.resource('dynamodb')
sample_table = dynamodbclient.Table('ec2metadata')

with open('/samplepath/spotec2interruptionevent.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# parse file
obj = json.loads(data)

#instance_id and cluster_id is the Key in dynamodb table 

    response=sample_table.put_item(
                              Item={
                                  'instance_id': instanceId,
                                  'cluster_id': clusterId,
                                  'event':obj

                              }
                              )
```